# Request Computer Name before running script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that stops a service then renames a folder on the local computer, i would like to be able to make a run remotely by asking the command executer to enter the machine name of where it would like to run the script then execute.

```bsh
try {
    Stop-service wuauserv -force
} catch {
    Write-error "Unable to stop the service WUAUSERV"
    start-sleep -seconds 5
    exit
}

try {
    Rename-Item "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution" "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.old" -force
} catch {
    Write-error "Unable to rename the folder :("
    start-service wuauserv
    start-sleep -seconds 5
    exit
}
start-service wuauserv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably have the script take a parameter by adding this at the top

```bsh
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$ComputerName
)
```

The `Mandatory` value will prompt the user to enter a value if it was not supplied.

Alternatively if you really want to manually ask the user you can use this:

```bsh
$ComputerName = Read-Host "ComputerName"
```

This will also prompt the user to enter a variable.

Then use `Invoke-Command` to run your logic on the remote computer

```bsh
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
  # Your code here..
}
```

Edit:
After your update, I notice you terminate the script by calling `exit`. I would advise you to use `return` instead. If someone runs this script from the commandline the script will kill the terminal, which is quite annoying.

Edit2: Here is a complete working example, with my recommendations:

```bsh
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory)][string]$ComputerName
)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptBlock {
    try {
        Stop-Service wuauserv -Force
    } catch {
        Write-error "Unable to stop the service WUAUSERV"
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        return
    }

    try {
        Rename-Item "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution" "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution.old" -Force
    } catch {
        Write-error "Unable to rename the folder :("
        Start-Service wuauserv
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        return
    }
    Start-Service wuauserv
}
```

Comment: You need to lookup how to format the code, that is not easy to read. Anyway, you are calling `Enter-PSSession` in there, that was not in my example. I will update with a complete working example.

Comment: Sorry about that, Thank you

Comment: I keep getting the below messag when i enter a computer name "Connecting to remote server LN-T48-PC19RG1P failed with the following error message : The user name or 
password is incorrect."

Comment: ignore my last comment, it does work, Thank you very much!!